# Slider initial value not applying

Tags: nativescript

In my nativescript 2.5.0 application I have a slider that is defined as:

```html
<Slider id="slider" class="slider" value="{{ amount }}" minValue="{{ minAmount }}" maxValue="{{ maxAmount }}" />
```

When the page is loaded in the on navigatingTo event I am setting the model with the corresponding values (amount, minAmount, and maxAmount):

```js
var model = null;
function onNavigatingTo(args) {
 page = args.object;
 model = new Observable();
  
  model.set('amount', 100);
  model.set('maxAmount', 500);
  model.set('minAmount', 0);

 page.bindingContext = model;
}
```

I also have a label that is bound to the "amount" property showing the slider selection.

On Android, when the page is loaded the slider is correctly set to 100, but in iOS the slider is set to 0 even though the "amount" property is set correctly and the label displays "100"

I tried getting a reference of the slider in the loaded event and setting the value manually there, but this did not work either.

Am I missing something?  Is there something else I need to configure to make this work in iOS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue and the reason for this to happen is because in your code the value is set via view model (binding). In this case the slider iterates and assigns the values as declared in the XML layout - meaning that it will try to assign a value of 300 to **value** property but at this very moment the values for **minValue** and **maxValue** are still the default ones (0 and 100) and this is causing the problem.The solution is pretty straight forward - when using binding to assign the initial values of your Slider declare first the minValue and **maxValue** (to create the limits) and only then assign the actual **value** within those limits.

e.g. based on your code snippet

```
<Slider minValue="{{ minAmount }}" maxValue="{{ maxAmount }}" value="{{ amount }}" />
```

The only difference with your code is that value is now at the end and the slider will first create min and max values and only then it will be able to assign a value of 300.
 Demonstration project can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/others/t_1115173).

Comment: Thank you Nick.  This worked perfectly.  Perhaps this is good candidate for a note in the documentation.